# jQuery pushing an array into an array

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to push an array into array but i'm getting an error.  I can't actually see the error due to the page being redirected(due to wordpress) before i can check google devtools.

Here is my code

```
var lang_array=[];
table.children("tbody").children("tr").each(function(i) {
    var english = $(this).find("input[name='english_input[]']").val();
    var transliteration = $(this).find("input[name='transliteration_input[]']").val();
    var persian = $(this).find("input[name='persian_input[]']").val();
    var array = [];

    array.push({
        english:english,
        transliteration:transliteration,
        persian:persian 
    });

    lang_array.push({label:'language',data:array});
});

console.log(lang_array);
```

How do i solve?

Comment: Use Chrome's developer tools and change the settings to so that preserve log is checked.

Comment: My guess would be a problem related to your selectors that look like this: `input[name='english_input[]']` you should be escaping the inner brackets by placing two \ before each.

Comment: An alternative (to escaping) would be using prefixed selector: `.find('[name^=english_input]')`.

Comment: Could you post your HTML so I can reproduce the issue? (at least your tbody)